# Pithru karya and modern purohits

Tags: scripture, rituals, pitru

Nowadays Pithru Karya is not being performed with proper religious injunctions.

What will happen if:

1. one does not perform the Pithru Karya at all or
2. on the other hand if performed by a Purohit who's telling the mantras fast and the doer cannot follow them and utters them incorrectly.

What will be the retro effect for both (person and priest) in these circumstances?

Comment: @swiftpushkar--thanks for ur reply---The second part of the question is a debate--why cannot you try for an answer?

Comment: If you are having a sacred thread you can do the pitru kriya like shraddha and tarpan , yourself , if you are not wearing sacred thread then there is no way out.

Comment: thx yogi for ur reply. But there have to be two swamigals and a vathiyar.I am a iyengar and doing amavasya tharpan on my own. But pithru karya  divas am is different.